Python tkinter quiz app, correct answers shown as wrong
I'm kind of a beginner in python and tkinter. I made a basic quiz app for a project in college, which displays random 10 questions out of a dict of 30 questions.
In the QUESTIONS dictionary, each question has 4 answers with the first being the correct answer. In the generate_quiz() function, each question has a correct answer shuffled amongst 3 others. At the end of the quiz, it resets everything when going back to the main menu. When selecting correct answers in the 1st round the quiz goes smoothly, but when I restart the quiz and choose the same correct answers it displays them as wrong. This only happens for the questions that are in common with the ones from the previous round, the new questions have no such issue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here's the entire code:
from tkinter import *
import random

QUESTIONS = {
    "What is the capital of France?": ["Paris", "London", "Berlin", "Madrid"],
    "Who wrote 'To Kill a Mockingbird'?": ["Harper Lee", "Mark Twain", "Jane Austen", "J.K. Rowling"],
    "What is the largest planet in our solar system?": ["Jupiter", "Mars", "Earth", "Venus"],
    "What is the chemical symbol for water?": ["H2O", "CO2", "O2", "NaCl"],
    "Who was the first president of the United States?": ["George Washington", "Thomas Jefferson", "Abraham Lincoln", "John Adams"],
    "What is the square root of 64?": ["8", "6", "7", "9"],
    "Who painted the Mona Lisa?": ["Leonardo da Vinci", "Vincent van Gogh", "Pablo Picasso", "Claude Monet"],
    "What is the longest river in the world?": ["Nile", "Amazon", "Yangtze", "Mississippi"],
    "What is the smallest country in the world?": ["Vatican City", "Monaco", "Nauru", "San Marino"],
    "What is the fastest land animal?": ["Cheetah", "Lion", "Tiger", "Leopard"],
    "Who discovered penicillin?": ["Alexander Fleming", "Marie Curie", "Louis Pasteur", "Isaac Newton"],
    "What is the hardest natural substance on Earth?": ["Diamond", "Gold", "Iron", "Silver"],
    "What is the capital of Japan?": ["Tokyo", "Beijing", "Seoul", "Bangkok"],
    "Who wrote '1984'?": ["George Orwell", "Aldous Huxley", "Ray Bradbury", "J.R.R. Tolkien"],
    "What is the chemical symbol for gold?": ["Au", "Ag", "Pb", "Fe"],
    "What is the tallest mountain in the world?": ["Mount Everest", "K2", "Kangchenjunga", "Lhotse"],
    "What is the main ingredient in guacamole?": ["Avocado", "Tomato", "Onion", "Garlic"],
    "Who is known as the father of computers?": ["Charles Babbage", "Alan Turing", "John von Neumann", "Bill Gates"],
    "What is the largest ocean on Earth?": ["Pacific Ocean", "Atlantic Ocean", "Indian Ocean", "Arctic Ocean"],
    "What is the speed of light?": ["299,792,458 meters per second", "150,000,000 meters per second", "186,282 miles per second", "300,000,000 meters per second"],
    "Who painted the ceiling of the Sistine Chapel?": ["Michelangelo", "Raphael", "Leonardo da Vinci", "Donatello"],
    "What is the capital of Australia?": ["Canberra", "Sydney", "Melbourne", "Brisbane"],
    "Who wrote 'Pride and Prejudice'?": ["Jane Austen", "Charlotte Bronte", "Mary Shelley", "Emily Dickinson"],
    "What is the chemical symbol for oxygen?": ["O", "O2", "Ox", "Og"],
    "What is the largest mammal in the world?": ["Blue Whale", "Elephant", "Giraffe", "Hippopotamus"],
    "What is the smallest bone in the human body?": ["Stapes", "Femur", "Tibia", "Fibula"],
    "Who invented the telephone?": ["Alexander Graham Bell", "Thomas Edison", "Nikola Tesla", "Guglielmo Marconi"],
    "What is the primary language spoken in Brazil?": ["Portuguese", "Spanish", "French", "English"],
    "What is the result of 1 + 1?": ["2", "3", "1", "0"],
    "What is the capital of Canada?": ["Ottawa", "Toronto", "Vancouver", "Montreal"]
}

MAX_SCORE = 10   
questions = random.sample(list(QUESTIONS.items()), 10)
score = 0
message_label = None
answer_selected = None

# Defining all functions

def display_frame(frame):
  frame.tkraise()  

def create_welcome_frame():
  welcome_frame = Frame(container, bg = 'gray12')
  welcome_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')

  title_label = Label(welcome_frame, text = "QuizApp", font = ('Arial', 24), fg = 'white', bg = 'gray12')
  title_label.pack(fill = X, pady = 30)

  welcome_label = Label(welcome_frame, text = 'Welcome to QuizApp! Press the \'Start\' button to begin the quiz.', font = ('Arial', 20), fg = 'white', bg = 'gray12', pady = 40)
  welcome_label.pack(pady = 20)

  start_button = Button(welcome_frame, text = 'Start', font = ('Arial', 24), fg = 'white', bg = 'SpringGreen2', padx = 20, pady = 20, command = generate_quiz_frame)
  start_button.pack(pady = (60, 0))

  return welcome_frame

def create_quiz_frame():
  quiz_frame = Frame(container, bg = 'gray12')
  quiz_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')

  return quiz_frame

def generate_quiz():
  global questions, answer_selected

  if questions:
    global question

    question, answers = questions.pop(0)
    correct_answer = answers[0]

    question_label = Label(quiz_frame, text = question, font = ('Arial', 25), fg = 'white', bg = 'gray12', pady = 40)
    question_label.pack(anchor = W, padx = (200, 0))

    random.shuffle(answers)

    for answer in answers:
      answer_selected = False

      answer_button = Button(quiz_frame, text = answer, width = 30, pady = 17, font = ('Arial', 19), command = lambda chosen_answer = answer: display_quiz_message(chosen_answer, correct_answer))
      answer_button.pack(anchor = W, padx = (200, 0), pady = 10)
  else:
    display_frame(results_frame)
    update_results_frame()

def display_quiz_message(chosen_answer, correct_answer):
  global message_label, score, answer_selected

  if not answer_selected:

    if message_label:
      message_label.destroy()

    message = ''
    message_color = ''
    answer_selected = True

    if chosen_answer == correct_answer:
      message = 'You got it correct!'
      message_color = 'SpringGreen3'
      score += 1
    else:
      message = 'You got it wrong...'
      message_color = 'red2'

    message_label = Label(quiz_frame, text = message, font = ('Arial', 20), fg = message_color, bg = 'gray12')
    message_label.pack(anchor = W, padx = (200, 0))

    next_button = Button(quiz_frame, text = 'Next', font = ('Arial', 15), command = lambda: clear_frame(quiz_frame))
    next_button.pack(anchor = W, padx = (200, 0), pady = (20,0))
  else:
    pass

def clear_frame(frame):
  for widget in frame.winfo_children():
    widget.destroy()

  generate_quiz()

def generate_quiz_frame():
  generate_quiz()
  display_frame(quiz_frame)

def create_results_frame():
  
  results_frame = Frame(container, bg = 'gray12')
  results_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')

  return results_frame

def update_results_frame():
  for widget in results_frame.winfo_children():
    widget.destroy()

  results_label = Label(results_frame, text = f"Your score: {score} / {MAX_SCORE}", font = ('Arial', 20), fg = 'white', bg = 'gray12', pady = 40)
  results_label.pack(anchor = CENTER)

  button = Button(results_frame, text = 'Back to main menu', font = ('Arial', 24), fg = 'white', bg = 'SpringGreen2', padx = 20, pady = 20, command = reset_quiz)
  button.pack(anchor = CENTER, pady = (60,0))

def reset_quiz():
  global questions, score, answer_selected
  questions = random.sample(list(QUESTIONS.items()), 10)
  score = 0
  answer_selected = None
  display_frame(welcome_frame)

# Main app window
master = Tk()
master.title('QuizApp')
master.config(bg = 'gray12')

# Container for all frames
container = Frame(master, bg = 'gray12')
container.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)

container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

welcome_frame = create_welcome_frame()
quiz_frame = create_quiz_frame()
results_frame = create_results_frame()

display_frame(welcome_frame)

master.mainloop()

I tried fixing it with chatgpt but the code it generates doesn't work properly either.
I tried closing and opening VSCode.

I sill having problem: What is capital of Japan. I selcted Tokyo. And got me wrong answer and so on.

after applying sharim's solution i'm facing no errors in that question or any question, it should be tokyo

The problem is in your generate_quiz() function, you wrote this line of code in this function to shuffle the answers.
random.shuffle(answers)

Now the problem happens because the nature of the list is mutable, which means even if you update the list through another function this will update that in the original place,
So that means this will update the list of answers you have in your QUESTIONS dictionary.
So because of this, for the first time, you will have the correct answers, because you are getting them before this line executes, but for the next round, the correct answers will shuffle in the list.
So instead of using the original list to shuffle, you can shuffle the copy of answers so that it will only update the answers in a copied list not in the original place
To do that you can use the .copy() method.

def generate_quiz():
  global questions, answer_selected

  if questions:
    global question

    question, answers = questions.pop(0)
    answers = answers.copy() # Copy the original list
    correct_answer = answers[0]

    question_label = Label(quiz_frame, text = question, font = ('Arial', 25), fg = 'white', bg = 'gray12', pady = 40)
    question_label.pack(anchor = W, padx = (200, 0))

    random.shuffle(answers)

    for answer in answers:
      answer_selected = False

      answer_button = Button(quiz_frame, text = answer, width = 30, pady = 17, font = ('Arial', 19), command = lambda chosen_answer = answer: display_quiz_message(chosen_answer, correct_answer))
      answer_button.pack(anchor = W, padx = (200, 0), pady = 10)
  else:
    display_frame(results_frame)
    update_results_frame()

Other than that you can also use

This will also copy the list

answers = answers[:]


And another one is, instead of copying only the answer, just copy the whole question, now because our question is a dictionary with a list as a value we can't use a simple copy method because it will create a shallow copy, means that dictionary will be copied but the value that is list in this case will still reference to the original data.

so For that we can use the deepcopy() method from the library called copy.
Here's how to do it
from copy import deepcopy

...



def generate_quiz():
  global questions, answer_selected

  if questions:
    global question

    question, answers = deepcopy(questions.pop(0)) # copy the whole question
    correct_answer = answers[0]

    question_label = Label(quiz_frame, text = question, font = ('Arial', 25), fg = 'white', bg = 'gray12', pady = 40)
    question_label.pack(anchor = W, padx = (200, 0))

    random.shuffle(answers)

    for answer in answers:
      answer_selected = False

      answer_button = Button(quiz_frame, text = answer, width = 30, pady = 17, font = ('Arial', 19), command = lambda chosen_answer = answer: display_quiz_message(chosen_answer, correct_answer))
      answer_button.pack(anchor = W, padx = (200, 0), pady = 10)
  else:
    display_frame(results_frame)
    update_results_frame()


...


Oh man thanks for helping me out, works perfectly! You saved me a lot of time trying helplessly to figure out the problem haha. I did not know about the deepcopy, or that copying a dictionary will still copy list value's reference instead of value.

Apart from answer of Sharim09 who has explained your issue, another way is to use a shuffle function that does not modify the list in place: random.sample() which you have already used for randomly selecting 10 questions.
Just replace the following line
random.shuffle(answers)

by
answers = random.sample(answers, len(answers))


what's the difference between both lines? does shuffle modify the list but sample does not?

Yes, sample() does not modify the list, it returns a new list instead.
